# C++: Undefined behavior caused by...?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

```
int size = 0;
int sorted[] = {};
int symbols[] = {8, 9, 13, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 20, 20, 27, 
    32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 44, 45, 46, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
    50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 
    55, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
    77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 93, 112, 113, 
    114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 160, 161, 161, 162, 162, 
    163, 164, 164, 165, 186, 186, 186, 187, 187, 187, 188, 188, 188, 188, 189, 
    189, 189, 190};

int i = 0;
while(symbols[i] != 190){
    size++;
    if(symbols[i+1] == 190) {
        size++;
    }
    i++;

}

int indx = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
    if(symbols[i] != symbols[i+1]) {
        sorted[indx] = symbols[i];
        indx++;
    }
}
```

I cannot locate the problem. What could cause undefined behavior? Size variable after the for loop becomes 27 (supposed to be 123), which I do not change. Got totally lost and cannot figure out where the problem stems from.

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't `int sorted[] = { }` create an array with zero elements?

Comment: No, it doesn't create an array with zero elements (unless the compiler supports that as an extension), because C++ doesn't allow arrays with zero elements. It's simply an error in standard C++, and if the compiler accepts it anyway, the behaviour is outside of the scope of the standard regardless of anything else in the program.

Comment: C++ supports arrays with zero elements. Just not as declared variables.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You're right, zero is a valid array length in a `new T[0]` construct, but that isn't the case here :)

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I won't use it the same ever again. Something new learnt!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int sorted[] = {}
```

OK... so sorted is an array with no elements. Some compilers will warn about this:

```
test.cpp(217) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
```

But let's assume it works for your compiler and creates an array of constant size 0... Then what? Your code does this:

```
sorted[indx] = symbols[i];
```

Hey! What's going on here... `sorted` doesn't have space to store anything. That write results in undefined behavior - it may crash, it may overwrite memory or it may cause your computer to add... *one... hundred... billion... dollars* to your bank account.

Comment: hmm.. compiler doesn't cause any errors. I was actually using it this way before and thought that I can declare an array of an unknown size, which I can fill with data later.

Comment: in this case behavior is undefined, anything can happen, and you need not get any diagnostics. In A and C++ the programmer must know the ules enough to ask only things that are reasonable.

Comment: @decas C and C++ don't let you do this. You must allocate the space you need explicitly (either on the stack, via something `int sorted[200]`, or on the heap via something like `int *sorted = new int[200]` followed by `delete[] sorted` when you're done with it).

Comment: @decas Since you're using C++, you may consider `std::vector` useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
int sorted[] = {}
```

This creates an array with 0 elements.

Comment: Your answer is entirely useless to someone who doesnt know that this is forbidden.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb to be fair, even if it weren't forbidden, OP goes on to use the array as if it had a non-zero size.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Wrong (and agressive just like you always are): the array is subscripted as if it was `size - 1` elements wide.

Comment: I do not intend to be aggressive in a bad way. I just stated what is my opinion about your answer in a direct way.

Comment: @juan this answer does not raise that problem to the readers awareness. It would become useful if it contained such explanations.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to run your compiler in a more... restrictive mode than it runs by default, just to disable the most thoughtless compiler extensions. This applies to virtually all compilers out there.

In your case

```
int sorted[] = {};
```

is completely ill-formed C++ code, which is required to trigger diagnostic message. An there's a very good reason for that diagnostic message to be an *error* message specifically, not a mere warning.

Strictly speaking, even though there are quite a few weird extensions compilers implement, I'm still surprised that there's one that allowed this declaration to slip through. What compiler is that?

Just tried it myself and discovered that GCC actually accepts this. What were they thinking this time? What is it for? To support local declarations for "struct hack"-ed objects with a trailing array of zero size? Something else?

Comment: "To support local declarations for "struct hack"-ed objects with a trailing array of zero size?" Yes, that's exactly the reason why GCC supports zero-length arrays, according to their [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length).

Comment: @celtschk: Thanks. That makes sense. But still, it shoudn't really be that difficult to distinguish between these contexts and still issue the diagnostics for cases like this one.